# VBA Whitelist - match against whitelist then delete specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to creat a macro that matches against a whitelist, then delete everything that's not on the whitelist. I have the following code:

```
Sub WHITELIST()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
If IsError(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Whitelist").Columns("A"), 0)) Then .Rows(i).Delete
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

But my code deletes the entire row. I only want to delete the range A:B and shift the cells up (the row size is variable so i always want to check till the last row - up to 40.000 rows). Its important that "important Data" doesn't gets deleted too. Here is an example how the macro SHOULD work:

[image]

Hope someone can help me

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
 If IsError(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Whitelist").Columns("A"), 0)) _
 Then .Rows(i).Delete
```

to this

```
    If IsError(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Whitelist").Columns("A"), 0)) _
 Then .Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

This will only delete the cells in `columns` A and B.

Using the `Shift:=xlUp` will allow you delete those specific cells in the range you define and move the entire block of cells below that range up.